# Why cant I convert a specific element in a string to int[] ? C#

Tags: c#, string, text, int

A `.txt - file` is being read into a single string. The first 14 elements should be the first 14 elements in a array. The code is as follows:

```
 // The file "read.txt" is being read 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");

        // In this section each line is being read.
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            // This line ables the program to differ between variables and numbers. 
            string[] arr = s.Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
                {
                    M_array_0[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]);
                }
        }
```

The error in this specific problem reads:

> An unhandled execptionof type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

As additional information the error 'FormatException was unhandled' displayes:

> Additional Information: input string was not in a correct format.

Why is it not in the correct format? and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do the lines in your file look?

Comment: Are there empty strings in `arr`? If you attach a debugger it should break on the bad input in your loop.

Comment: You may check if an `arr[i]` contains other characters than digits before casting the string to int. There are several ways, like `int.TryParse`, or you may use LINQ to check for chars other than digits.